What is the most efficient AVX2/512 code sequence to merge two registers with sorted values?
I have had students write code that efficiently sorts 8 and 16 32-bit numbers at a time in parallel using avx2 and avx512. The easy way is to load 8 or 16 registers, and implement an optimal sorting network n=8 or 16. Let's take the case for n=8. In 19 swaps, 8 values can be sorted, and doing it on 8 avx2 registers, we have 8 groups of 8 sorted numbers.
I would like to take this to the next step, and transpose the registers so each group of sorted numbers is in a single register. The question is, what is the most efficient way to do this (without writing to memory). Transposing would mean that each register would contain 8 (or 16 for avx512) sorted values.
The second part is, let's assume we have two registers containing sorted values: ymm0 and ymm1. How can I  merge the values in the registers to produce ymm2 and ymm3 so the whole thing is sorted?
Alternatively, can the merging be done in the 8 registers with numbers sorted vertically?
For example:
ymm0 = 1, 12,  ...
ymm1 = 4, 13,  ...
ymm2 = 9, 15,  ...
ymm3 = 11, 19, ...
ymm4 = 20, 21, ...
ymm5 = 22, 33, ...
ymm6 = 49, 34, ...
ymm7 = 52, 35, ...

Ok, we ignore the other numbers in the rest of each register. Instead of transposing, I could just merge these two lists, putting the results in two other vector registers. If this is better, then it would be necessary to process the first two numbers, then shift each register to bring the next two numbers into place.
